# How do I use fbcunn nn.HSM

Tags: neural-network, torch

I'd love a simple example of how to use the nn.HSM hierarchical softmax module in fbcunn.

The documentation is nonexistent ([see here](http://facebook.github.io/fbcunn/fbcunn/#fbcunn.README.How_to_use_them_)). I did find [this user group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/ji18vxnYN7U) which describes what the cluster "mapping" should look like, and there are some tests lying around for the module and its corresponding criterion but none of them use the module in a "normal" way, e.g. as the final layer in a simple feed-forward neural network.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example that should work:

```lua
require 'torch'
require 'fbcunn'

hidden_dim = 10
input_dim = 20
batch_size = 1

gpuid = 0

function to_cuda(x) return gpuid >= 0 and x:cuda() or x end

inputs = to_cuda(torch.rand(batch_size, input_dim))
targets = to_cuda(torch.ones(batch_size):long())

-- #mapping should equal the number of possible outputs, in our case 8
-- this mapping defines 4 clusters, two size 2, one size 3, one size 1
mapping = { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 2} }
linear = to_cuda(nn.Sequential():add(nn.Linear(input_dim,hidden_dim)))
hsm = to_cuda(nn.HSM(mapping, hidden_dim))

h_out = linear:forward(inputs)
s_out, err = hsm:forward(h_out, targets)
df_ds = hsm:backward(h_out, targets)
linear:backward(inputs, df_ds)
```

Note that as of this posting, the above example will only work on a GPU (cannot run on CPU, aka `gpuid=-1`); See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/fbcunn/issues/101).

Additionally, the GPU must have compute capability 3.5 or greater; the example at the link above provides an even smaller example that will run on a GPU with compute capability 3.0.

Comment: Hi Emma, I am trying to install fbcunn. After it's installation when I do 'require fbcunn' it throws an error saying async_rng torch module does not exist. Did you get the same error? However, doing 'libfbcunn' doesn't throw as error. Can I still use this? Also, what is the loss function we need to use for HSM?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar I don't think this is the right venue for this discussion, but I didn't encounter this issue. My first guess would be that fbtorch didn't install properly. My second comment is that I don't think fbcunn is really maintained anymore (Facebook uses TensorFlow now) and I wouldn't recommend using it -- I'd switch to TensorFlow or (particularly if you aren't swimming in GPU resources) roll-your-own in Torch.

Comment: Hi Emma, thanks a lot for your comment. Just a quick question. Does Facebook not use Torch anymore? Is it official that they have moved to tensorflow? Would really appreciate anyreference please.

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar No references on that, just word of mouth -- new interns working on deep learning are told to learn TensorFlow and not Torch. I'm sure some still use Torch but overall there is movement towards TensorFlow.

Comment: ah ok, thats very interesting. :-)